# Linker script for an nrf52 S132 Bootloader

Tags: linker, embedded, firmware, nrf52

I'm currently building a bootloader suitable for Dual Channel DFU and SD132. It is on nrf52832, currently on PCA10040. Although the linker script works, and creates a hex file, I am left with an `app_error_code 1` after `nrf_sdh_enable_request()`, from `sd_softdevice_enable()`.

Is it the LS's fault? Have I completely missed the mark? Or is it something completely different. Feel free to ask for more details, I've included the LS, as I'm unsure of what else to add.

Thanks

---

*Below is what I have so far, cobbled together from the various examples in the SDK.*

```
SEARCH_DIR(.)
GROUP(-lgcc -lc -lnosys)

GROUP(S132_softdevice.o)
MEMORY
{
  FLASH_SOFTDEVICE (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x00023000
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x24000, LENGTH = 0x6CA00
  SRAM_SOFTDEVICE (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x0005C10
  RAM (rwx) :  ORIGIN = 0x20005C11, LENGTH = 0x9D6F

  /** Location of non initialized RAM. Non initialized RAM is used for exchanging bond information
   *  from application to bootloader when using buttonluss DFU OTA.
   */
  NOINIT (rw) :  ORIGIN = 0x2000F97F, LENGTH = 0x80

  /** Location of bootloader setting in flash. */
  BOOTLOADER_SETTINGS (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x0007F000, LENGTH = 0x1000

  /** Location in UICR where bootloader start address is stored. */
  UICR_BOOTLOADER (r) : ORIGIN = 0x10001014, LENGTH = 0x04

  /** Location of mbr params page in flash. */
  MBR_PARAMS_PAGE (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x0007E000, LENGTH = 0x1000

  /** Location in UICR where mbr params page address is stored. */
  UICR_MBR_PARAM_PAGE(r) : ORIGIN = 0x10001018, LENGTH = 0x04
}

SECTIONS
{
  /* Place the bootloader settings page in flash. */
  .bootloaderSettings(NOLOAD) :
  {

  } > BOOTLOADER_SETTINGS

  /* Write the bootloader address in UICR. */
  .uicrBootStartAddress :
  {
    KEEP(*(.uicrBootStartAddress))
  } > UICR_BOOTLOADER

  /* Place the mbr params page in flash. */
    .mbrParamsPage(NOLOAD) :
  {

  } > MBR_PARAMS_PAGE

  /* Write the bootloader address in UICR. */
  .uicrMbrParamsPageAddress :
  {
    KEEP(*(.uicrMbrParamsPageAddress))
  } > UICR_MBR_PARAM_PAGE

  /* No init RAM section in bootloader. Used for bond information exchange. */
  .noinit(NOLOAD) :
  {

  } > NOINIT
  /* other placements follow here... */
}

SECTIONS
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .softdevice :
  {
    KEEP(*(.softdevice))
    FILL(0xFFFFFFFF);
    . = 0x00023000;
  } > FLASH_SOFTDEVICE

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .softdevice_sram :
  {
    FILL(0xFFFFFFFF);
    . = 0x00005C10;
  } > SRAM_SOFTDEVICE

  .svc_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_svc_data = .);
    KEEP(*(.svc_data))
    PROVIDE(__stop_svc_data = .);
  } > RAM

  .fs_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_fs_data = .);
    KEEP(*(.fs_data))
    PROVIDE(__stop_fs_data = .);
  } > RAM

  .log_dynamic_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_log_dynamic_data = .);
    KEEP(*(.log_dynamic_data))
    PROVIDE(__stop_log_dynamic_data = .);
  } > RAM

  .cli_sorted_cmd_ptrs :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_cli_sorted_cmd_ptrs = .);
    KEEP(*(.cli_sorted_cmd_ptrs))
    PROVIDE(__stop_cli_sorted_cmd_ptrs = .);
  } > RAM
} INSERT AFTER .data;

SECTIONS
{
  .dfu_trans :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_dfu_trans = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.dfu_trans*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_dfu_trans = .);
  } > FLASH

  .pwr_mgmt_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_pwr_mgmt_data = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.pwr_mgmt_data*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_pwr_mgmt_data = .);
  } > FLASH

  .log_const_data :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_log_const_data = .);
    KEEP(*(.log_const_data))
    PROVIDE(__stop_log_const_data = .);
  } > FLASH

  .cli_command :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_cli_command = .);
    KEEP(*(.cli_command))
    PROVIDE(__stop_cli_command = .);
  } > FLASH

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .sdh_stack_observers :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_sdh_stack_observers = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_stack_observers*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_stack_observers = .);
  } > FLASH

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .sdh_req_observers :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_sdh_req_observers = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_req_observers*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_req_observers = .);
  } > FLASH

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .sdh_state_observers :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_sdh_state_observers = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_state_observers*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_state_observers = .);
  } > FLASH

  /*.sdh_ant_observers :
  *{
  *  PROVIDE(__start_sdh_ant_observers = .);
  *  KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_ant_observers*)))
  *  PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_ant_observers = .);
  *} > FLASH
  */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .sdh_ble_observers :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_sdh_ble_observers = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_ble_observers*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_ble_observers = .);
  } > FLASH

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .sdh_soc_observers :
  {
    PROVIDE(__start_sdh_soc_observers = .);
    KEEP(*(SORT(.sdh_soc_observers*)))
    PROVIDE(__stop_sdh_soc_observers = .);
  } > FLASH

} INSERT AFTER .text

INCLUDE "nrf5x_common.ld"
PROVIDE(_sbss = __bss_start__);
PROVIDE(_ebss = __bss_end__);
PROVIDE(_sdata = __data_start__);
PROVIDE(_sidata = __etext);
PROVIDE(_estack = __StackTop);
PROVIDE(_edata =__data_end__);
PROVIDE(__isr_vector = __StackTop);
```

Comment: linker script and bootstrap at a minimum are intimately connected, possibly other library or application code.  So linker script by itself is only a part of the equation.

Comment: Do you have any idea of where to look next @old_timer ?

Comment: You say you have an SDK?  Is it incomplete?  Did it not come with any examples, a manual, etc?  It should just work and be able to build working binaries.

Comment: It did! But of course the sample projects are limiting, and I've had to adapt the linker